# Jquery положить элементы в div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Нужно положить элементы в div - `<div style='flex-direction: column;'>`.

Див нужно создать после `p` с `id="billing_city_field"`
и закрыть его после `p` с `id="apartment_field"`.
Пытался это сделать с помощью этой функции:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#billing_city_field").after("<div style='flex-direction: column;'>");
    $("#apartment_field").after("</div");
});
```

Но див сразу же закрывается. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или вопрос задан не правильно, или же Вы требуете невозможное... 
Если нужно обернуть элемент с `id=apartment_field` внутри элемента с `id=billing_city_field` в `div`, то вот код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    let apartmentField = $("#apartment_field");
    $("#billing_city_field").html(`<div style='flex-direction: column;'>${apartmentField}</div>`);
});
```

Грубо говоря, код данную структуру -

```
<div id="billing_city_field">
    <div id="apartment_field"></div>
</div>
```

Превращает в такую -

```
<div id="billing_city_field">
    <div style="flex-direction: column">
        <div id="apartment_field"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```